# Reading files in For-loop fashion in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have some files with `YYYYMMDD` date code in it. For example, my20150112.csv. How do you make a for-loop in R so that R will automatically process the next date after it finishes processing the previous date. 
Here are the scripts below:

```
R_script -> function(file){
   read.csv(file)
}
```

For example, how would you make the script run `R_script(my20150112.csv)` automatically after it run `R_script(my20150111.csv)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach

```
files = dir(pattern =".csv") #Obtain the names of all files
file_dates = gsub("[^0-9]", "", files) #Obtain the numeric value in each file
require(anytime) #We'll use anytime package
file_dates = anydate(file_dates) #Convert the numeric values to dates
files = files[order(file_dates)] #Order the files according to dates

for (i in 1:length(files)){ #Run your operations
    df = read.csv(file = files[i]) 
    #YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: How do you set which date the files will end. Lets say you only want to process my20150111.csv to my20150130.csv only even though you have up to my20151230.csv. See the top question for more information.

Comment: Can anybody see my final edited version. Good response d.b. but sometiems, there is so much file it is difficult to manually remove every one of them.

Comment: Can you please show me using cond? And also, does the above approach if the file you want is in http:// domain, that will automatically download the file when you enter the URL?

Comment: @erver, you should add more information about the source of files, when you want to exclude files, and what you want to do with them. I'm sure I (and others) will try to help you. But more information will be useful.

Comment: @d.b, it is a nice solution, just one comment for this particular case, you don't need `anytime` package, because `file_date` can be sorted like a character string.

Comment: @DavidLeal, I agree. I figured if the dates were parsed, it would allow excluding files before certain dates or after certain dates conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your individual files all have the same format:

```
setwd(<directory where files are>)
for (x in list.files()) {
  file <- read.table(i, header=TRUE)  # Not sure if you have headers or not
  assign(x=as.character(x), value=file, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an end to end solution. The following function validates the file name syntax and also whether it is a valid date or not. It includes range date filter. See the comments inside the function for more information.

```
processYYYYMMDDFiles <- function(path = getwd(), start, end) {
    path <- normalizePath(path)
    # The regular expression for a file
    regEx = "^my\\d{8}\\.csv$"
    # A more precise regular expression for a valid YYYYMMDD
    # ^my(19|20)\\d\\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\.csv$

    # Finding all possible files in the path folder
    listFiles = dir(path = path, pattern=regEx)

    # Selecting just files with valid dates (not just the format, also a valid one, for 
    # example is 20170229 is not a valid one, but it is valid syntactically) 
    # Extracting the date information: YYYYMMMDD
    datesOfFiles <- substring(listFiles, 3, 10)

    # Internal function for validating a date
    checkDate <- function(YYYMMDDdate) {
        return(!is.na(as.Date(as.character(YYYMMDDdate),
        tz = 'UTC', format = '%Y%m%d')))
    }

    # Checking
    datesOfFilesCheck <- sapply(datesOfFiles, checkDate)

    # Reporting about not valid dates
    listFilesNOK = listFiles[datesOfFilesCheck == FALSE]
    if (length(listFilesNOK) > 0) {
        msg = paste("From folder: '%s' skiping the following files,",
                "because they have not a valid date:'%s'")
        msg = sprintf(msg, path, toString(listFilesNOK))
        message(msg)
    }

    # Filtering for only valid date within the interval [start, end]
    validIdx <- (datesOfFilesCheck == TRUE) & 
        (datesOfFiles >= start) & (datesOfFiles <= end)
    listFiles <- listFiles[validIdx]
    listFiles <- listFiles[order(listFiles)] # sorting
    nFiles = length(listFiles)

    print(sprintf("Processing files from folder: '%s'", path))
    for (i in 1:nFiles) {
        iFile = listFiles[i]
        # Here comes the additional tasks for this function
        print(sprintf("Processing file: '%s'", iFile))
    }
}
```

Now testing the function creating temporary files in a temp directory:

```
# Testing
files <- c("my20170101.csv", "my20170110.csv", "my20170215.csv", "my20170229.csv", 
   "my20170315.csv", "my20170820.csv")
tmpDir <- tempdir()
file.create(file.path(tmpDir, files), overwrite=T)

processYYYYMMDDFiles(path = tmpDir, start="20170101", end="20170330")
print("Removing the testing files...")
print(file.remove(file.path(tmpDir, files)))
```

It produces the following output:

```
> source("~/R-workspace/projects/samples/samples/processYYYYMMDDFiles.R", encoding = "Windows-1252")
From folder: 'C:\Users\dleal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoZLcNS' skiping the following files, because they have not a valid date:'my20170229.csv'
[1] "Processing files from folder: 'C:\\Users\\dleal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpoZLcNS'"
[1] "Processing file: 'my20170101.csv'"
[1] "Processing file: 'my20170110.csv'"
[1] "Processing file: 'my20170215.csv'"
[1] "Processing file: 'my20170315.csv'"
[1] "Removing the testing files..."
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I hope this would help

Comment: where would you put the function scripts to process the file in the code above. and does .csv files with "http://" in the beginning work too?

Comment: @erver you can put the script at the location of your preference, you just have to specify the correct `path` as input argument. It could be relative to the script location or absolute, it does matter. I use `normalizePath` for validating the path information and generating an operative system specific location. You mean locate files under `"http://"` protocol, that would depend on the `dir` function. You can test it, I didn't, I don't know if for this case you need any other function for example: [download.file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html)